# Extreme Directions

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-geometry

I am trying to show that: Prove or disprove: An unbounded n-dimensional polyhedral set can have at most n extreme directions.

**My attempt:** I try to create some counter-examples with $n=2$ and $n=3$ cases, however these do not work out well. In each of the cases, we have at most $n$ extreme directions. Also, I try to draw some graphs for $n=2$ case, but it did not work either:(

**PS:** I try to use the following theorem from the lecture notes: Let $K = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: Bx \le 0\}$ be a pointed nontrivial polyhedral cone. A nonzero vector $d \in K$ generates an extreme ray of $K$ if and only if among the inequalities $b_i^Tx \le 0$ for $i=1,2,...k$ defining $K$ there are at least $n-1$ linearly independent inequalities which are active at $d$.

Can anyone give any hints/ideas,please?

Thank you very much, in advance:)

Comment: What is your concept of an "extreme direction"? It would seem to me that a regular hexagon would have three extreme directions, though existing in only two dimensions.

Comment: What I mean by extreme direction is the following: A vector $u$ is called an **extreme direction** of $K$, if the ray generated by $u$ is an extreme ray, thanks in advance:)

Comment: Then I guess I need to know that it means for $n-1$ inequalities to be "active at $d$", because any sensible interpretation I can think of would have every direction in regular hexagon as extreme, since only one inequality would need to be active.

Comment: An inequality is active if it is satisfied as an equality.

Comment: And since only one active inequality is needed in $\Bbb R^2$, there is such a point in every direction from the center of the hexagon (or more generally, for any convex polygon with the origin inside). So every direction is extreme.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, if I understand your answer correctly, your set is bounded.

Comment: I see - that is what I was missing. I kept asking questions because it seemed too trivial, so I assumed I was misunderstanding something. But even then, the example is easily modified to be unbounded in some directions, while leaving infinitely many others as extreme.

Comment: I guess that is really finishing the job, thank you very much:)